# TI 89 vs TI 84 Plus CE

Tags: calculator

I am currently a sophomore in high school taking Algebra 2 and Precalculus in the same year. Junior year I’ll be taking AP BC Calculus and then Senior year Multivariable Calculus. I currently have a TI 84 (regular), and I was wondering which calculator to get next? I understand I won’t be able to rely on a calculator to solve literally everything, and that’s not even what I want. Thank you!

Comment: Probably the best people to ask are the ones who will be teaching the classes you plan to take.

Comment: Maybe you could report back to us on what they told you, Jon.

Comment: Today would be a good day to do that.

Comment: I bought the TI 89 for a few reasons. 1: I can do all of the algebra very easily by hand, and so when I get to college, and I know that I know basic algebra, I don’t have to spend time factoring, FOILing, etc. But the calculus operations are amazing. The 89 has limits, and a button for infinity. It also has more coordinate systems which are useful for physics. The 3D graphing is very cool because it helps you understand how the graphing works. All around more advanced and a long term option. Only problem is that it may take a while to get used to.

Comment: @Jondue Could you convert your comment to an answer? You are permitted to answer your own questions, and it seems like you've solved your problem and made a decision, so there's not much room for anyone else to give you input.

That said, as someone who's used both a TI-84 and a TI-89, getting the 89 was indeed a good long-term decision; I found myself having to break problems down into reasonable chunks for the 84 to tackle, whereas the 89 can do many of those same problems all at once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I bought the TI 89 for a few reasons. 1: I can do all of the algebra very easily by hand, and so when I get to college, and I know that I know basic algebra, I don’t have to spend time factoring, FOILing, etc. But the calculus operations are amazing. The 89 has limits, and a button for infinity. It also has more coordinate systems which are useful for physics. The 3D graphing is very cool because it helps you understand how the graphing works. All around more advanced and a long term option. Only problem is that it may take a while to get used to.